# “D’entre eux” to mean “of them”

Tags: sens, choix-de-mot, pronoms-personnels

I’ve seen this before, and a literal translation would be “between them.” I’m wondering why you can’t simply say *d’eux* because I’d think the *de* would suffice, but in typing it out, I’ve realized it sounds exactly like *deux.* So perhaps it’s to avoid confusion?

Examples:

- *Certains **d’entre eux** sont-ils toujours à vendre ?*
- *Aucun **d’entre eux** ne pourrait le croire.*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

L'emploi varie selon certains facteurs et d'autres réponses se sont déjà intéressées aux exemples en question. Plus généralement, contrairement à ce qu'on affirme en question, il n'est pas impossible d'utiliser la forme disjointe du pronom directement après la préposition *de* (*d'[eux](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/eux)*).

---

Ce qui se passe c'est qu'il y a concurrence entre *de* et *d'[entre](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/entre/0)* dans certains cas : « dans une expression partitive, comme complément d'une expression nominale, d'un numéral cardinal, d'un adjectif au superlatif, de pronoms démonstratif, interrogatif, indéfini » (LBU14). *Le bon usage* (Grevisse et Goosse, éd. De Boeck/Duculot, 14<sup>e</sup>) ancre son analyse (§ 662 c 5°) dans une évaluation d'un propos que l'on trouve au TLFi :

> Quantificateur + *d'* + **entre**. *Entre* exprime l'ensemble, par
>   opposition à l'unité ou à la fraction de l'ensemble. *Entre* est
>   facultatif si le quantificateur est au sing. : *(l')un d'eux/l'un
>   d'entre eux, aucun d'eux/aucun d'entre eux, chacun d'eux/chacun
>   d'entre eux* ; il est obligatoire lorsque le quantificateur désigne
>   une pluralité : *certains, plusieurs, un bon nombre, la majorité, la
>   plupart, une centaine, etc. d'entre eux* [...] (TLFi, [*entre*](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/entre/0))

- Le LBU14 préfère qualifier de *rare* le cas où l'on trouverait *de*
  avec le quantificateur désignant la pluralité, et surtout devant un
  pronom de la troisième personne (rare : « Un grand nombre **d'eux** en
  sont originaire », Barrès).
- Il remet en doute l'aspect facultatif (de dire *d'entre*) quand le quantificateur est au
  singulier, dans d'autres cas qu'avec *chacun, aucun* et *l'un, un, pas un* (donc avec des cas comme *à qui*, *quelqu'un* etc.) ; on
  indique que *de nous/vous* sont « possibles » mais *d'eux/d'elles* « rares
   », sauf s'ils sont accompagnés d'un numéral ou de *tous* (rare : « Quelqu'un **d'eux** se sera mal conduit » Stendhal).
- Il affirme que *d'entre* serait « peu adéquat » pour introduire un ensemble où il
  n'y a que deux éléments (typique : « Je saurai qui **de vous** deux a le
  magot », Zola).
- Il ajoute qu'après un superlatif, indépendamment du nombre, *d'entre* est « nettement » prédominant (typique : « Les chevaux en liberté prennent
  le plus beau **d'entre eux** comme chef », Balzac).

[ Si l'on suivait ces prescriptions et l'analyse qui précède, *(d')entre* serait obligatoire avec le premier exemple (*certains...*) et facultatif avec le deuxième (*aucun...*) ; *aucun d'eux* serait rare, puisque *d'eux* n'est pas accompagné d'un numéral ou de *tous*. ]

---

Incidemment, on peut noter qu'avec des expressions quantitatives, *d'entre* marque « une insistance plus grande que *de* seul » ( « Ceux d'entre ces blessés qui sont en état de quitter leur lit », Duhamel) et permet « de mieux identifier un complément qui ne suit pas son support » ( « D'entre plusieurs souris blanches qu'on croise [...] avec des souris noires, l'une produira des souris noires, tandis qu'une autre produira des souris panachées, et une autre encore des souris grises », J. Rostand) (LBU14, § 1061 c 2°)

Comment: Merci mille fois, tu m’as bien fourni avec une nouvelle perspective. Il me semble qu’on puisse utiliser « d’entre » si tout échoue. D’ailleurs je ne savais pas que « d’entre eux » doit s’utiliser quand le quantificateur désigne une pluralité. Maintenant je le sais. :)

Comment: @tssmith2425 Avec plaisir. Note cependant qu'il faut revoir ces constats avec le temps parce que comme les autres réponses le montrent, certains usages finissent par en supplanter d'autres, et le LBU se veut descriptif de l'usage... (et le TLFi n'est plus mis à jour depuis 1994).

Answer (score 3):

***Certains d'entre eux*** is almost the only form used while ***aucun d'entre eux*** has only reached ***aucun d'eux*** popularity in the last decades.

Before that, ***aucun d'eux*** was by far the most popular, as shows the following Google Ngram:
[image]
[image]

The possible confusion with ***deux*** is then unlikely to play a major role.

This can be confirmed by looking to the feminine variants, where no confusion exists but that follows a similar evolution.

[image]

With ***chacun***, the form without ***d'entre*** is still leading:

[image]

The tendency is then for the forms with ***d'entre*** to lead but confusion with ***deux*** is unlikely to be the cause of it. A possible explanation is that the other expressions tend to follow the ***certains d'entre eux*** form, which was always either the only one used or by far the most popular. I have never heard ***certains d'eux***.

Answer (score 3):

"Certains d'eux" is practically not used in comparison with "[certains d'entre eux](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=certains+d%27eux%2Ccertains+d%27entre+eux&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ccertains%20d%27%20eux%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ccertains%20d%27%20entre%20eux%3B%2Cc0)". Things are different for "[aucun d'eux](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=aucun+d%27eux%2Caucun+d%27entre+eux&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Caucun%20d%27%20eux%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Caucun%20d%27%20entre%20eux%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Caucun%20d'%20eux%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Caucun%20d'%20entre%20eux%3B%2Cc0)" and "aucun d'entre eux" as the situation has essentially been the inverse and as only now "aucun d'eux" seems to be used equally with "aucun d'entre eux".

The case of use of "d'" instead of "d'entre" appears to be the exception.

ceux d'entre eux ([ngram1](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=ceux+d%27entre+eux%2Cceux+d%27eux&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cceux%20d%27%20entre%20eux%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cceux%20d%27%20eux%3B%2Cc0)) plupart d'entre eux ([ngram2](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=plupart+d%27entre+eux%2Cplupart+d%27eux&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cplupart%20d%27%20entre%20eux%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cplupart%20d%27%20eux%3B%2Cc0)), une partie d'entre eux ([ngram3](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=une+partie+d%27entre+eux%2Cune+partie+d%27eux&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cune%20partie%20d%27%20entre%20eux%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cune%20partie%20d%27%20eux%3B%2Cc0)), un nombre d'entre eux ([ngram4](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=un+nombre+d%27entre+eux%2Cun+nombre+d%27eux&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cun%20nombre%20d%27%20entre%20eux%3B%2Cc0)), beaucoup d'entre eux ([ngram5](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=beaucoup+d%27entre+eux%2Cbeaucoup+d%27eux&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cbeaucoup%20d%27%20entre%20eux%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cbeaucoup%20d%27%20eux%3B%2Cc0)), plusieurs d'entre eux ([ngram7](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=plusieurs+d%27entre+eux%2Cplusieurs+d%27eux&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cplusieurs%20d%27%20entre%20eux%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cplusieurs%20d%27%20eux%3B%2Cc0)), uns d'entre eux ([ngram8](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=uns+d%27entre+eux%2Cuns+d%27eux&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cuns%20d%27%20entre%20eux%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cuns%20d%27%20eux%3B%2Cc0))

un d'eux ([ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=un+d%27entre+eux%2Cun+d%27eux&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cun%20d%27%20entre%20eux%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cun%20d%27%20eux%3B%2Cc0))

We can see that among the forms most often used "d'entre eux" ([ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=*+d%27entre+eux&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t2%3B%2C%2A%20d%27%20entre%20eux%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bcertains%20d%27%20entre%20eux%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bun%20d%27%20entre%20eux%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bplupart%20d%27%20entre%20eux%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Buns%20d%27%20entre%20eux%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bnombre%20d%27%20entre%20eux%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bplusieurs%20d%27%20entre%20eux%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bbeaucoup%20d%27%20entre%20eux%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bceux%20d%27%20entre%20eux%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bdeux%20d%27%20entre%20eux%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BCertains%20d%27%20entre%20eux%3B%2Cc0#t2%3B%2C*%20d'%20entre%20eux%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bcertains%20d'%20entre%20eux%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bun%20d'%20entre%20eux%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bplupart%20d'%20entre%20eux%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Buns%20d'%20entre%20eux%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bnombre%20d'%20entre%20eux%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bplusieurs%20d'%20entre%20eux%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bbeaucoup%20d'%20entre%20eux%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bceux%20d'%20entre%20eux%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bdeux%20d'%20entre%20eux%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BCertains%20d'%20entre%20eux%3B%2Cc0)) is always the form used either in great majority or exclusively and that in only  one case (un d'eux, aucun d'eux), is the trend reversed "un d'eux" being used more often; a rule can be made to the effect that "d'entre eux" is always correct and (bar two exceptions) preferable,  and that only in rare cases is "d'eux" acceptable.

The translation of "certains 'entre eux" is not "some between them" though; it is "some amongst them"; "entre eux" will be "between them" in the following case;

- The supervisor split the task between them.